# Backface Culling Causing Transparency, Flipping doesn't FIX

Tags: blender, culling

I have a weird model. I imported an FBX liquor bottle and the sides are transparent in the viewport. It seems to render opaque during CYCLES, but I need the bottle to render properly in the viewport for a number of reasons. I'm submitting the BLEND file to see if anyone can get this fixed. I've worked with the latest version 2.92 and the latest 2.93 BETA. Nothing fixes this problem. Again, **FLIPPING** or **RECALCULATING NORMALS** does nothing.

[image]

Here's the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgw06mdi6bsn5u3/bottle-test.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The FBX came with a Material that was corrupt. Once I created a NEW material and simply attached a new Image Texture plugin, automatically mapped to the correct location in the provided image. This is a heavily documented problem online.